# Issues when calling to a function, C++

Tags: string, vector, split

I need help please.

I made a code which purpose is to modify a value at a specific place in a .txt. My first idea was to store all my .txt in a vector, then to deal with that vector.

For that I created 2 functions : One is basically splitting a line of the .txt, the other one is to find the good line in the txt., when found, the line is splitted by calling the first and then I can modify the value for the wanted one.

Well more or less, you can read my code following :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

vector<string> split(string myData) {
    vector<string> temporary;
    string delim = " ";
    string buf= "";
    int i = 0;
    while (i < myData.length()) {
        if (myData[i] != delim)
            buf += myData[i];
        else if (myData[i] == delim) {
            if (buf != ""){temporary.push_back(buf);}
            buf = "";
        } 
        i++;
    }
    return temporary;
}

void test (){
    fstream yourfile;
    string line, someString;
    vector<string> fichier;
    someString = "EnergySampler";
    ofstream monflux("/Users/geant4_simulation_20210413/results/myFile1MeV.txt");
    ifstream myFile("benchmark.txt");
    double number;
    
//////STORING THE .TXT IN VECTOR    
    
    if (myFile){
        while (getline(myFile,line)){
            fichier.push_back(line);
        } //end while
    } //end if
    else cerr << "Your file couldn't be opened";
     
////LOOKING FOR THE LINE AND MODIFY IT    

    for (int i(0); i<fichier.size(); i++) {
        size_t found = fichier[i].find(someString);
        if(found != string::npos){ // si existe
            //cout << fichier[i] << endl;
            vector<string> splitted ;
            splitted=split(fichier[i]);      // problem here...
            cout << splitted.size() <<endl;
            
            
            for (int k = 0; k < splitted.size(); k++){
                //number = strtod(splitted[k],&end);
                cout << splitted[i] << endl;
            }
            
            
        } //end if
    }
    
    myFile.close();
}
```

When I test independently the splitting function, it works well, it returns the line stored for each string in a vector.

For instance : `split("$       DOUBLE       EnergySampler     0.019 $")`

returns

`(std::vector<std::string>) { "$", "DOUBLE", "EnergySampler", "0.019" }`

So far so good ! I just want to pick the "0.019".

But when calling the function inside the test() function there is a problem, the vector I got from using : `splitted=split(fichier[i]);`
appears to have only 2 values whereas you can see above that my line contains 4.

My question then : why the `split()` works when calling independently and not when call from inside a function ?

Merci d'avance.

PS : I'm compiling my function with ROOT, a C++ interpreter.

Comment: Are you sure the `delim` in `benchmark.txt` are all spaces? They could be also `TABs` (`\t`) no?

Comment: Yes I checked it takes all the spaces, well with my text file it was working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the code looks pretty OK, I see two bugs on it.

1. I'm not sure if this is on purpose, but the `split` function never returns the last match. In your example, calling `split("$ DOUBLE EnergySampler 0.019 $")` would return the vector `["$", "DOUBLE", "EnergySampler", "0.019"]`. Note the missing `"$"` at the end of the vector. So, to fix this you'd need to check if `buf` is not empty at the end of the function like below (Also, looks like `ROOT` interpreter accepts comparing `char` with `string`, but I properly defined `delim` as `char` in the fix):

   ```cpp
   vector<string> split(string myData) {
       vector<string> temporary;
       char delim = ' ';
       string buf= "";
       int i = 0;
       while (i < myData.length()) {
           if (myData[i] != delim)
               buf += myData[i];
           else if (myData[i] == delim) {
               if (buf != ""){temporary.push_back(buf);}
               buf = "";
           }
           i++;
       }
       if (buf != ""){temporary.push_back(buf);}
       return temporary;
   }
   ```
2. Second, when you iterate over the `splitted` vector you're using the `i` index variable (from the outer `for`) instead of the `k` index variable from the inner `for`. If I fix it like below it works:

   ```cpp
           for (int k = 0; k < splitted.size(); k++){
               //number = strtod(splitted[k],&end);
               cout << splitted[k] << endl;
           }
   ```

So, running it for the `benchmark.txt` below:

```
$ DOUBLE EnergySampler 0.019 $
$ DOUBLE Dummy 0.123 $
$ DOUBLE EnergySampler 0.018 $
$ DOUBLE Dummy 0.321 $
$ DOUBLE EnergySampler 0.017 $
```

It would output the following:

```
5
$
DOUBLE
EnergySampler
0.019
$
5
$
DOUBLE
EnergySampler
0.018
$
5
$
DOUBLE
EnergySampler
0.017
$
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the detailed answer, clear for me ! Now I can do what I wanted.